# ES6 destructuring: Array reordering mechanism

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I was reading through [Kyle Simpson's book (You don't Know JS - ES6 and beyond)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md) and he gives this example on reordering arrays:

```
 var a1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    a2 = [];

[ a2[2], a2[0], a2[1] ] = a1;

console.log( a2 );                  // [2,3,1]
```

Can someone help me understand what's happening (I was expecting it to return [3, 1, 2]). If I input other elements, it gets more confusing:

```
[ a2[2], a2[0], a2[0] ] = a1; // [3, undefined, 1]
[ a2[1], a2[0], a2[0] ] = a1; // [3, 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=%20var%20a1%20%3D%20%5B%201%2C%202%2C%203%20%5D%2C%20a2%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%5B%20a2%5B2%5D%2C%20a2%5B0%5D%2C%20a2%5B1%5D%20%5D%20%3D%20a1%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%20a2%20)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B2%2C3%2C1%5D) to find out what the code compiles down to. (I've annotated the output with additional comments.)

```
var a1 = [1, 2, 3],
    a2 = [];

a2[2] = a1[0];  // a1[0] = 1
a2[0] = a1[1];  // a1[1] = 2
a2[1] = a1[2];  // a1[2] = 3
console.log(a2); // [2,3,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The positions in the destructuring pattern map to the indexes in the source array. So it's equivalent to:

```
a2[2] = a1[0];
a2[0] = a1[1];
a2[1] = a1[2];
```

The result you were expecting would come from:

```
a2 = [ a1[2], a1[0], a1[1] ];
```

This is the opposite of destructuring.

This one:

```
[ a2[2], a2[0], a2[0] ] = a1;
```

never assigns to `a2[1]`, so you get undefined for that element. You assign to `a2[0]` twice, first from `2` and then from `3`, so the final value is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple.

Destructing an array in ES6 is basically like this:

If you have

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

This means that when you write something like

```
[a, b, c, d] = arr;
```

You are actually saying this

```
a = arr[0];
b = arr[1];
c = arr[2];
d = arr[3];
```

Notice that the position of `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` corresponds to the index of the array `arr`, such that if you write

```
[a, c, b, d] = arr;
```

What you really mean is

```
a = arr[0];
c = arr[1];
b = arr[2];
d = arr[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

It just combine two steps of destructuring and adding values to `arr2` in one step. It is same as if you did this.

```js
 var a1 = [1, 2, 3],
   a2 = [];

var [one, two, three] = a1;
a2[0] = two;
a2[1] = three;
a2[2] = one
console.log(a2)
```